# How to export NDWI images one by one?

Tags: export, landsat-8, normalized-difference-water-index

I am using GEE and I'm pretty new with this engine. I'm trying to download several images from Landsat collection. I provide the script for you. 
Here is my question: 
How can I download each NDWI image as a separate file (rename it with the date and path&row) and export them into my Google Drive so I can use them with different software?

```
Map.centerObject(geometry2);
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_TOA')
.filterDate('2019-03-01','2019-04-30')
.filterBounds(geometry2);
print(landsat);
Map.addLayer(landsat,{bands : ['B6','B5','B3'],min: 0, max: 1});


var NDWI = landsat.map(function(img){
  var index = img.normalizedDifference(['B3','B5']);
  var clip = index.clip(geometry2);
  var id = img.id();
  return clip.rename(id);
});


print(NDWI,'NDWI');


var stack = NDWI.toBands();
print(stack,'stack');
Export.image.toDrive({
  image : stack,
  description : 'NDWIstack',
  scale : 30,
  region : geometry2,
  maxPixels : 1e10});
```

This script maps the NDWI function on all images in the specific location and within the specific time range (from March 2019 to the end of Apr 2019). The result is **395** NDWI images. When I stack them (using **toBands()** ) all images become ONE image with 395 bands (am I right?) When I export them I find the images with wrong names (please note that I am using the ID of each image to rename the output images). The images are also more than the results (i.e. 395). For example for a very smaller region (geometry) the results is 9 images. When I export them into my Google Drive the images are 42! and of course with names like "NDWIstack-0000011008-0000055040.tif". I downloaded one image and I cannot open it in any image processing software (ArcMap, ENVI)

[image: As an alternative way can I download the features before stacking them into one image?]

[image: When I use 'stack', the result is an image with 395 bands which are all NDWI bands]